# flickr Gadgets on Blogger

Tags: blogger, flickr, gadget

What I want is a way to attach Flickr photos and photo sets to individual posts on a blogger.com blog.  I want to include all of the descriptive text, and possibly comments, roughly as it would appear on the corresponding page on flickr.com, but I don't want it to contain any of the headers and footers normally seen on those pages, except possibly for just the flickr logo to give due credit.  I'm not too concerned whether the attached content is inline, in an iframe, or appears as a pop-up window, so long as it otherwise seems to be reasonably integrated.

Is there a reasonable way to do this, or will I have to find my own solution (write some javascript glue)?

Answer (score 1):

Don't think it is possible for blogger.com blog. However, it is possible if you use self-hosted [WordPress](http://wordpress.org) blog and install Flickr plugin.